# UpdateOrCreate for multiplate tables, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a function for create, but the code for update it's pretty similar so I want to modify the function to use `UpdateOrCreate` insted.

```
// Register table
$register = new Register();
$register->updateOrCreate(
    ['id' => $person],
    [
    'volume' => $request->volume,
        // more columns
]);

// Person table
$person = new Person();
$person->updateOrCreate(
    ['id' => $request->register.id],
    [
    'name_as_written' => $request->name_as_written,
    //more columns
]);
// $person->register()->associate($register)->save(); // right now, this is used for create


// Relationship table
foreach ($request->relationship_values as $item) {
    $relationship = new Relationship();
    $relationship->updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $item.id],
        [
        'relative_surname' => $item['relative_surname'],
        //more columns
    ]);

  //  $relationship->person()->associate($person)->save(); // right now,this is used for create
};
```

Comment: try `sync` method instead of `associate`: `$relationship->person()->sync($person);`

Comment: what do you want to happen ? please elaborate more your question

Comment: I have a param (ID), if this ID exists I want to make an update, else I want to save data, and I find UpdateOrCreate, that I think that may work in my case.